# What replaced Indy TIdHTTP.DoRequest?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-5

I just moved Indy 10 into Delphi 5 with the help of some users here. I use to post using,

`HTTP.DoRequest(hmPost,URL,ssSource,ssResult);//This will not disconnect if already connected like the post`

Since DoRequest is not longer available, if I try to use this code:

```
HTTP.Post(URL,ssSource,ssResult);
```

it works fine unless I try to post again within like 30 seconds. If I do I get this error:

```
ERROR: Socket Error # 10048. Address already in use.
```

DoRequest never caused this. Not sure how to replace it correctly.

Comment: `DoRequest()` still exists, it is simply `protected`. You don't need to call it directly unless you are trying to send custom HTTP commands. To avoid `Post()` disconnecting, make sure the `hoKeepOrigProtocol` flag is enabled in the `HTTPOptions` property. As for your socket error, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: After looking at my logs I think the problem is all the posting is done within a thread, and I can have up to 3 threads running at the same time. Thread 2 and 3 always get a Socket Error #10048. When thread #1 finishes, it picks up the next post just fine. With Indy 9 and DoRequest().

Comment: are you trying to use the same `TIdHTTP` object in all of the threads, or do they each have their own `TIdHTTP` object? Are you using the `BoundIP` and/or `BoundPort` properties?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Didn't even have time to post my edit. Yes, I am using the same TidHTTp object. I am using the BoundPort since I thought that was the replacement for HTTP.Port in Indy 9. I don't, no ever have used BoundIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remy Lebeau, I wanted to thank you. I removed the HTTP.BoundIP altogether and now there is not socket error which means that indeed all 3 threads are now running at the same time truly in their own thread. Thanks it in.